# Please help me for printing these using split method

Tags: python, split

I am new to python. I have a small doubt in `split()` function. i want to split the lines after the string "successful". How do i use split method to do it.

```
File system activity

Opened files...

C:\27e7a559f98a0fbe14ba3a3cd8b4f3c2400c6581134a97c382e9d465b807fa87 (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\tac.exe (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\DOCUME~1\&lt;USER&gt;~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Templates\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)\\.\PIPE\lsarpc (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscui.cpl (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetcpl.cpl (successful)\\.\Ip (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll (successful)\\.\WMIDataDevice (successful)C:\WINDOWS\Registration\R000000000007.clb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\WindowsShell.manifest (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUC.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBD.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCIT.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBI.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdocvw.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMA.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMABD.TTF (successful)
```

the output should be like this

```
File system activity

Opened files...

C:\27e7a559f98a0fbe14ba3a3cd8b4f3c2400c6581134a97c382e9d465b807fa87 (successful)

C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\tac.exe (successful)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
In [31]: output = r"C:\27e7a559f98a0fbe14ba3a3cd8b4f3c2400c6581134a97c382e9d465b807fa87 (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\tac.exe (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\DOCUME~1\&lt;USER&gt;~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Templates\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)\\.\PIPE\lsarpc (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscui.cpl (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetcpl.cpl (successful)\\.\Ip (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll (successful)\\.\WMIDataDevice (successful)C:\WINDOWS\Registration\R000000000007.clb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\WindowsShell.manifest (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUC.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBD.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCIT.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBI.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdocvw.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMA.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMABD.TTF (successful)"

In [32]: while output:
   ....:     left, mid, output = output.partition("(successful)")
   ....:     print left+mid
   ....:     
C:\27e7a559f98a0fbe14ba3a3cd8b4f3c2400c6581134a97c382e9d465b807fa87 (successful)
C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\tac.exe (successful)
C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)
C:\DOCUME~1\&lt;USER&gt;~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)
C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Templates\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)
\\.\PIPE\lsarpc (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscui.cpl (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetcpl.cpl (successful)
\\.\Ip (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll (successful)
\\.\WMIDataDevice (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\Registration\R000000000007.clb (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\WindowsShell.manifest (successful)
C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUC.TTF (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBD.TTF (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCIT.TTF (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBI.TTF (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdocvw.dll (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMA.TTF (successful)
C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMABD.TTF (successful)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = r"C:\27e7a559f98a0fbe14ba3a3cd8b4f3c2400c6581134a97c382e9d465b807fa87 (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\tac.exe (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\DOCUME~1\&lt;USER&gt;~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Templates\1pb78m8n6he1l1565b3k36w7o7of8ksb88y53s63tpqg0vl (successful)\\.\PIPE\lsarpc (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscui.cpl (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetcpl.cpl (successful)\\.\Ip (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll (successful)\\.\WMIDataDevice (successful)C:\WINDOWS\Registration\R000000000007.clb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\WindowsShell.manifest (successful)C:\Documents and Settings\&lt;USER&gt;\Local Settings\Application Data\GDIPFONTCACHEV1.DAT (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUC.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBD.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCIT.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TREBUCBI.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\shdocvw.dll (successful)C:\WINDOWS\system32\stdole2.tlb (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMA.TTF (successful)C:\WINDOWS\FONTS\TAHOMABD.TTF (successful)"

sep='(successful)'
ls=output.split(sep)
for i in ls[:-1]:
    print i+sep
print ls[-1]
```